# Inicializar un struct dentro de otro struct

Tags: c++, struct

He creado un **struct tTiempo** compuesto por **dos int**, y otro **struct tRider que contiene una variable del tipo tTiempo** y **necesito inicializar disponible.horas = 13 y disponible.min = 0 dentro del struct tRider**, pero no sé como hacerlo, y no he encontrado ninguna pregunta sobre el tema.

```
struct tTiempo {
    int horas;
    int min;
};

struct tRider {
    tTiempo disponible;
    double ganancias = 0;
    lTiempo lSolicitados;
    lTiempo lIniciados;
    lTiempo lEntregados;
};
```

Comment: Veo que inicializas el miembro `ganancias` en `tRider`. Exactamente, ¿ Que problema has encontrado al hacer lo mismo con los miembros de `tTiempo` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes al menos 4 maneras de hacerlo:

1. **[Inicialización de agregado](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)**: Si asignas valores entres llaves (`{` y `}`) a una instancia de tipo agregado, los valores irán a parar a cada uno de los sub-elementos en orden de declaración:

   ```
   //                 ___ 0 se asigna al 2º sub-e.emento del primer sub-elemento de tRider.
   //                /
   //               ^
   tRider r = {{13, 0}};
   //           vv
   //            \___ 13 se asigna al 1r sub-elemento del primer sub-elemento de tRider.
   ```

   El resto de elementos no especificados en la lista entre llaves, se inicializan por defecto, por lo tanto el código a continuación tiene el mismo efecto que el anterior:

   ```
   tRider r = {{13}};
   ```

   Si el sub-objeto es también un agregado, se pueden omitir las llaves, por lo tanto el código a continuación tiene el mismo efecto que el anterior:

   ```
   tRider r = {13};
   ```
2. **[Mediante inicializadores designados](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers)** (C++20): Que consiste en asignar valores a los sub-elementos por su nombre:

   ```
   tRider r = { .disponible = { .horas = 13 } };
   ```

   El resto de elementos no nombrados se inicializan por defecto. Esta inicialización se puede combinar con la anterior:

   ```
   tRider r = { .disponible = { 13 } };
   ```
3. **Con un constructor**: Puedes usar el constructor para pasar valores a sub-elementos de tus objetos en el momento de construcción:

   ```
   struct tRider {
       tRider(const tTiempo &t) :
           disponible(t)
       {}

       tTiempo disponible;
       double ganancias = 0;
       lTiempo lSolicitados;
       lTiempo lIniciados;
       lTiempo lEntregados;
   };

   tRider r1({13, 0}); // 13 horas 0 min
   tRider r2({13});    // 13 horas 0 min
   ```

   Ten en cuenta que los elementos no inicializados en el constructor, no serán inicializados y tendrán valores residuales de memoria.
4. **Inicialización por copia**: Puedes usar un objeto por defecto para dar unos valores iniciales, personalizando el resto de valores posteriormente:

   ```
   constexpr tTiempo TRECE_EN_PUNTO = { 13, 0 };
   constexpr tRider DEFAULT_RIDER = { TRECE_EN_PUNTO };

   tRider r = DEFAULT_RIDER;
   r.disponible.min = 30; // 13 horas 30 min
   ```

O también puedes usar cualquier combinación de todas esas maneras.

Answer (score 0):

Primero accedes a `disponible` de la estructura `tRider` y luego a `horas` y `min`.

```
tRider rider;
rider.disponible.horas = 13;
rider.disponible.min = 0;
```

Si quieres que los `tRider` se inicien con esos valores por defecto puedes hacerlo en el constructor.

```
struct tRider {

    ...
    
    tRider() {
        disponible.horas = 13;
        disponible.min = 0;
        // Equivalente a
        // this->disponible.horas = 13;
        // this->disponible.min = 0;
    }
}
```